# What is difference between return "redirect:login"; and return "login";?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

can any one tell me the actual difference between  return "redirect:login";  and return "login"; because when i use return "redirect:login"; i got error like  "The requested resource is not available" and when i use return "login"; its work.

Comment: A redirect consists in sending a response to the browser asking it to go to another URL. That's what the redirect: prefix tells Spring to do. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx

Answer (score 1):

In the case of,

- **`return "login"`** : The `RequestDispatcher` issues a `RequestDispatcher.forward(...)` . The view name is resolved by the configuration you have did. So, if you had an `InternalResourceViewResolver`with JSP view, i would lookout for `login.jsp`
- **`return redirect:\login`** : The `RequestDispatcher` allows the view to handle the request. `RedirectView` invokes `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect("login")`. Which also means that server doesn't handle the extra trip to the view and the browser handles it. You can see the URL on the browser to ***login.jsp*** in that case.

I suppose that you should do `return "redirect:/login"` (you need the slash) for your redirect to work.